# How to save Card Info For further use

Tags: node.js, next.js, card

i want to save customer Card infromation for fruther use so customer don't have to fill the card infromation again and again. i am using, nextjs, stripe and nodejs.
How can i do that in a safe and protected manner.

Is there is any method to use the card infromation again and again for .

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with nextjs or node and its a bad idea to store customer data in your servers without proper PII practices and certifications in place.

Since you are using stripe, they provide a mechanism to store cards for *off session* usage - https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#future-usage